# What does $script: do in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've seen this syntax on a variable before and not quite sure exactly what it is:

```
$script:Foo = "Bar"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The syntax `$script:Foo` is most commonly used to modify a script-level variable, in this case `$Foo`.  When used to read the variable, usually `$Foo` is sufficient. For example rather than write this:

```
verbose-script.ps1
$script:foo = ''
function f { $script:foo }
```

I would write this (less verbose and functionally equivalent):

```
script.ps1
$foo = ''
function f { $foo }
```

Where `$script:Foo` is crucial is when you want to modify a script-level variable from within another scope such as a function or an anonymous scriptblock e.g.:

```
PS> $f = 'hi'
PS> & { $f; $f = 'bye';$f }
hi
bye
PS> $f
hi
```

Notice that `$f` outside the scriptblock did not change even though we modified it to `bye` within the scriptblock.  What happened is that we only modified a local copy of `$f`.  When you don't apply a modifier like `script:` (or `global:`), PowerShell will perform a `copy-on-write` on the higer-scoped variable into a local variable with the same name.

Given the example above, if we really wanted to make a permanent change to `$f`, we would then use a modifier like `script:` or `global:` e.g.:

```
PS> $f = 'hi'
PS> & { $f; $global:f = 'bye';$f }
hi
bye
PS> $f
bye
```

Answer (score 8):

The `script:` prefix causes the name on the right hand side to be looked up in the script scope.  Essentially data which is local to the script itself.  Other valid scopes include global, local and private.

The help section for scope contains a bit of detail on this subject.

```
help about_Scopes
```

Comment: I bet you meant private.  :-)

Comment: so what happens when you dot-source a script with script: prefixes on functions and variables?

Comment: When you dot-source, the script scoped items get pulled into the script that is doing the dot-sourcing.

Comment: so if that happens to be the command line, there's no way to make anything in the script private is there? Specifically I'm wondering about some 'utility' functions I have in my profile that I can't seem to make invisible to the shell at large.

Comment: @Mike, indeed i did. It's amazing how bad my spelling can be for the simple words. I like to think my bad spelling's resulted in a good portion of the awarded "Copy Editor" badges as people correct it ;)

Comment: Just keep in mind that dot-sourcing is a special beast - anything visible in the script's scope is promoted to the scope in which the script is dot-sourced.  Also, usually this syntax `$script:foo` is verbose and exactly equivalent to `$foo` when the variable is defined outside any functions.  Where you typically use this syntax `$script:foo` is inside a function in your script that needs to modify the script level $foo variable.  If you modify just `$foo` inside a function, then the script level $foo isn't modified.  Think of it like "copy-on-write" - the function makes it owns copy of $foo.

Comment: Using `$foo:script` inside the function defeats the default "copy-on-write" behavior and modifies that script-level `$foo` variable.  In a system where "globals and script level" variables abound, the "copy-on-write" is kind of nice - prevents complete chaos and makes it more obvious when you're changing a global within a function.

Comment: @Keith: That's a great explanation. You should make it an answer with a small example or two.